# IManExt ImportCmd trouble

Tags: c#, logging, dms, autonomy, imanage

I have been writing a small application using C# to copy a document into an individuals 'My Documents' folder on our DMS server.

I've beased the code around the listing provided in the 'WorkSite SDK 8: Utilize the IMANEXT2Lib.IManRefileCmd to File New Document Folders' blog.

Using this code in a WinForm application I have no problems copying the file from the source folder into the users DMS 'My Documents' folder.

However if I use the code in a command line application/.dll or any other type of application (other than WinForm) during the copy process I receive the error messages;

1.

> Error occurred when try to log the event!
>
> IManExt: Error occurred when try to log the event!
>
> Access is denied.

2.

> The document was imported to the database, but could not be added to
>   the folder.
>
> IManExt: The document was imported to the database, but could not be
>   added to the folder.
>
> IManExt.LogRuleEventsCmd.1: Error occurred when try to log the event!
>
> IManExt.LogRuleEventsCmd.1: Access is denied.

Error occurred when try to log the event!

-%-

Does anyone know why I'd receiving the 'Access Denied' error messages when using a non-WinForms application to copy documents?
What would I need to do to get around this issue?

Any help would be amazing!

Code in place:

```
    public void moveToDMS(String servName, String dBName, String foldName)
    {
        const string SERVERNAME = servName; //Server name
        const string DATABASENAME = dBName; //Database name
        const string FOLDERNAME = foldName; //Matter alias of workspace

        IManDMS dms = new ManDMSClass();
        IManSession sess = dms.Sessions.Add(SERVERNAME);
        sess.TrustedLogin();

        //Get destination database.
        IManDatabase db = sess.Databases.ItemByName(DATABASENAME);

        //Get destination folder by folder and owner name.
        IManFolderSearchParameters fparms = dms.CreateFolderSearchParameters();
        fparms.Add(imFolderAttributeID.imFolderOwner, sess.UserID);
        fparms.Add(imFolderAttributeID.imFolderName, FOLDERNAME);           

        //Build a database list in which to search.
        ManStrings dblist = new ManStringsClass();
        dblist.Add(db.Name);

        IManFolders results = sess.WorkArea.SearchFolders(dblist, fparms);

        if (results.Empty == true)
        {
            //No results returned based on the search criteria.
            Console.WriteLine("NO RESULTS FOUND!");
        }

        IManDocumentFolder fldr = null;

        if (results.Empty == false)
        {
            //Assuming there is only one workspace returned from the results.
            fldr = (IManDocumentFolder)results.ItemByIndex(1);
        }

        if (fldr != null)
        {
            // Import file path
            string docPath = @"C:\Temp\";
            string docName = "MyWord.doc";

            // Create an instance of the ContextItems Collection Object.
            ContextItems context = new ContextItemsClass();

            // Invoke ImportCmd to import a new document to WorkSite database.
            ImportCmd impCmd = new ImportCmdClass();

            // The WorkSite object you pass in can be a database, session, or folder.
            // Depends on in where you want the imported doc to be stored.
            context.Add("IManDestinationObject", fldr); //The destination folder.

            // Filename set here is used for easy example, a string variable is normally used here
            context.Add("IManExt.Import.FileName", docPath + docName);

            // Document Author
            context.Add("IManExt.Import.DocAuthor", sess.UserID); //Example of a application type.

            // Document Class
            context.Add("IManExt.Import.DocClass", "BLANK"); //Example of a document class.
            //context.Add("IManExt.Import.DocClass", "DOC"); //Example of a document class.

            // Document Description (optional)
            context.Add("IManExt.Import.DocDescription", docName); //Using file path as example of a description.

            // Skip UI
            context.Add("IManExt.NewProfile.ProfileNoUI", true);

            impCmd.Initialize(context);
            impCmd.Update();

            if (impCmd.Status == (int)CommandStatus.nrActiveCommand)
            {
                impCmd.Execute();

                bool brefresh = (bool)context.Item("IManExt.Refresh");
                if (brefresh == true)
                {
                    //Succeeded in importing a document to WorkSite
                    IManDocument doc = (IManDocument)context.Item("ImportedDocument");

                    //Succeeded in filing the new folder under the folder.
                    Console.WriteLine("New document number, " + doc.Number + ", is successfully filed to " + fldr.Name + " folder.");
                }

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you monitor this anymore, but I was hoping maybe you could point me to where you got this code? I'm trying to interact with iManage/Worksite, but don't have access to any documentation cause of some annoying corporate politics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case this helps someone else.

It seems my issue was the result of a threading issue.

I noticed the C# winform apps I had created were automatically set to run on a single '`ApartmentState`' thread (`[STAThread]`).

Whereas the console applications & class library thread state and management hadn't been defined within the project and was being handled with the default .NET config.

To get this to work: In the console application, I just added the `[STAThread]` tag on the line above my Main method call.

In the class library, I defined a thread for the function referencing the `IMANxxx.dll` and set ApartmentState e.g.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PerformSearchAndMove));
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

In both cases ensuring single '`ApartmentState`' thread was implemented set would resolve the issue.